# Prove that there exists walks that each edge is in $G$

Tags: graph-theory

For some $k \in\mathbb{N}$, let $G$ be a connected graph with $2k$ odd-degree vertices, and any number of even-degree vertices. Prove that there exists $k$ walks such that each edge in $G$ is used in exactly one walk exactly once, assuming that the main theorem about Eulerian circuits is true for graphs with multiple edges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an extra vertex and join it to all odd-degree vertices, it has an eulerian circuit and that circuit in the original graph becomes $k$ walks with the desired property.

Comment: I was just writing down something in this direction. Note that this construction avoids multi-edges, thus the final remark in the OP is not needed.

Comment: Thank you. How would I prove that this is false if k is replaced by k-1?

Comment: It doesn't use the connectivity of $G$ either, but with the multi-edge comment, we can prove it for multi-graphs as well.

Comment: @RobertMcDonald just use $2k$ vertices and $k$ edges that form a maching.

Comment: Sorry I still don't know what you mean by that. can you expand on that for me?